# Rx .NET what is the right way to observe a function call

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm learning to do rx in .NET the right way and wondering what is the usual way to make an observable stream out of a remote function call.

At the moment, I just create a `Subject<T>` and call its `OnNext` function within the callback method.

Example:

```
subject.AsObservable().Where(...).Subscribe(...);
```

This is where I filter and subscribe to the observable.

```
await speechService.StartListeningAsync(f => OnSpeechCommandRecognized(f), 
                  cts.Token, OnError, interimResults).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is where I pass the callback method to the speech service.

```
private void OnSpeechCommandRecognized(StreamingRecognitionResult result)
{
    subject.OnNext(result);
}
```

This is where I call the `OnNext` function within the callback method.

Another way I was looking at was to call `Observable.Start` and subscribe to the returning observable, but I don't think this is the way to go.

Also i could wrap the call around an `Observable.Create`.

So my question is: Is this example the right way to subscribe to a method emitting results?

Comment: Wrap the call around an `Observable.Create` either way is cleaner and more performant than using `Subject`

Comment: There is an `Observable.FromAsync` operator that probably fits the bill better than anything else you're trying to do, but I can't be sure unless you'd post the signature for `StartListeningAysnc` and a [mcve] to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you used `Create` rather than a `Subject`?

Since your API returns a task which presumably won't complete until it's time to stop listening, you can use `FromAsync` to wrap that call and then create a closure to the `Create`'s observer. Subscribe to the inner observable, and you have an observable which, when subscribed to, will yield results from the `StartListeningAsync` callback until the associated task completes (or errors).

```
Observable.Create((observer, outerCancel) =>
    Observable.FromAsync(innerCancel =>
            speechService.StartListeningAsync(
                observer.OnNext,
                innerCancel,
                observer.OnError,
                interimResults
            ))
        .Subscribe(observer, outerCancel)
);
```